# How to get `geom_smooth()` to understand the formula in result of `lm()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, call, lm

I want to use [`geom_smooth()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/geom_smooth) to display an arbitrary fitted function.

I've generated a linear regression model with:

`fit <- lm(loss ~ hardness + strength, data = rubber)`

I want to use this model in a graph with the call:

```
ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
                formula = ????? something to do with *fit*, 
                col = "red")
```

using the `formula` parameter to refer to the formula used in the `fit`.

I can view the formula used by evaluating `fit$terms`, but how do I pass this to `geom_smooth()`?

All the examples I've seen have the formula written out explicitly, but I want to wrap this call in a function for use with arbitrary models.

I've tried passing in `fit$terms`, `str(fit$terms)`, `deparse(fit$terms)` `do.call(fit$terms)`, and all sorts of variations on the theme.

Comment: `deparse(fit$call)`?

Comment: Nope! 
“Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
object 'loss' not found”

But a nice try.

Comment: I'm not sure about this approach...but it works fine without a formula- if yo u just remove that line- as `geom_smooth` is expecting the 2 arguments from the `aes`

Comment: @Stephen, very true, but without the formula specified, it seems `geom_smooth()` recalculates the model using just the two variables plotted. I want it to use the model with more variables.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
formula = str(fit$call)
```

does what I want.

Thanks to jaySf for the pointer.